# Rendering data from MySQL in a WinForms applications

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

I have an application I'm trying to create, however I'm stuck.

I am trying to access the site's MySQL query within my code.

Right now I am just trying to test it, to make sure it works, but I'm having no luck with that.

I think I'm just overlooking something simple, but I'm not sure. Any help?

```
class DBConnect
{
    private MySqlConnection connection;
    private string server;
    private string database;
    private string uid;
    private string password;

    public List<string>[] list = new List<string>[1];

    public DBConnect()
    {
        Initialize();
    }

    private void Initialize()
    {
        server = "localhost";
        database = "XXX";
        uid = "XXX";
        password = "XXX";
        string connectionString;
        connectionString = "SERVER=" + server + ";" + "DATABASE=" + database 
            + ";" + "UID=" + uid + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + password + ";";

        connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
    }

    //this will open the connection to MySql
    private bool OpenConnection()
    {
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            return true;
        }
        //if there is a problem connecting, display one of the following connections
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            switch (ex.Number)
            {
                case 0:
                    MessageBox.Show("Cannot connect to server. Contact Admin");
                    break;
                case 1045:
                    MessageBox.Show("Invalid username/password, please try again");
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    //if the connection fails to connect to MySql server, the client will close the connection.
    private bool CloseConnection()
    {
        try
        {
            connection.Close();
            return true;
        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            return false;
        }
    }

    //Select statement
    public List<string>[] Select()
    {
        int firstNumber = 2058;
        **string query = "USE `db_order` SELECT `order_id` FROM `order_address` WHERE order_id=2058";**

        //create a list to store the results
        list[0] = new List<string>(0);

        //Open's connection
        if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
        {
            //creates a command from the query.
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
            //creates a data reader, and executes the command.
            MySqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (dataReader.Read())
            {
                list[0].Add(dataReader["order_id"] + "");
            }

            //close Data Reader
            dataReader.Close();

            this.CloseConnection();

            //returns list to be displayed
            return list;
        }
        else
        {
            return list;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the second class (i got rid of anything that isn't a part of the problem):

```
public partial class Form1
{
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        // CustName
        // 
        this.CustName.AutoSize = true;
        this.CustName.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(200, 30);
        this.CustName.Name = "CustName";
        this.CustName.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(137, 13);
        this.CustName.TabIndex = 0;
        this.CustName.Text = "Customer\'s name goes here" + new DBConnect().list[0];


    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Any exception message returned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**

You add to the list from your `DataReader` like this

```
  list[0].Add(dataReader["order_id"] + "");
```

So, which means you have a `multi-dimensional` (2-dimension to be exact) array of list. Therefore to access that you have to do like `Select()[0][0]` , check below:

```
DBConnect() DBCon = new DBConnect();

this.Custname.Text = DBCon.Select()[0].Count>0 ? "Customer\'s name goes here" +DBCon.Select()[0][0].ToString() : "No Customer to show";
```

Comment: Hi,

the site has more then one database, so I either need the use statement, or access it in some other way.

Comment: You know, that did something, but now its telling me I have a connection problem. Maybe that means its working? im not sure.
well it is progress.

Comment: It could be a networking problem. Are you trying to connect via the Internet? your own network? or just localhost?

Comment: ok, i fixed the admin popup i was getting. I think.

Now it runs, but the output is "Customer's name goes here System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]

lol.